# 3 Simple Javascript lines NOT WORKING !

Tags: javascript

these lines :

```
var theSrc=document.getElementById('sb_image_'+id).src;
var srcLn=(theSrc.length)-12;
theSrc.substr(0,srcLn);
```

are Not working ! , the output is the same as `document.getElementById('sb_image_'+id).src` if i `alert(theSrc);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-assign the variable to the result:

```
theSrc = theSrc.substr(0, srcLen);
```

The call to `substr` does not change the original string. Instead it returns a **new** string to you.

Comment: so simple yet i couldn't notice that ! Seems i have to get some rest now ... thanks